# RxSwift - Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, generics, rx-swift

I have an UITableView and a `countries` variable whose signature is like:

```
let countryArray = ["Bangladesh", "India", "Pakistan", "Nepal", "Bhutan", "China", "Malaysia", "Myanmar", "Sri Lanka", "Saudi Arabia"]
```

When I'm trying to bind this array of countries in a UITableView, Its showing the error `Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred`.

Here is the snippet that I am doing:

```
let countries = Observable.just(countryArray)
    countries.bindTo(self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "myCell",
                                        cellType: MyCell.self)) {
                                            row, country, cell in
                                            // configuring cell
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the latest version of RxSwift. What you're using right now is deprecated. Your error may be related to it.

There are two ways to do what you're doing:

```
let countryArray = ["Bangladesh", "India", "Pakistan", "Nepal", "Bhutan", "China", "Malaysia", "Myanmar", "Sri Lanka", "Saudi Arabia"]
let countries = Observable.of(countryArray)

// Be sure to register the cell
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
```

1. To provide the cell type in the `items(cellIdentifier:cellType:)`, that's basically what you are doing:

   ```
   countries
       .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "myCell", cellType: MyCell.self)) { (row, element, cell) in
           // configure cell
       }
       .disposed(by: disposeBag)
   ```
2. To provide the cell factory closure, in other words dequeue the cell in the closure and return it:

   ```
   countries
       .bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { (tableView, row, element) in
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)) as! MyCell
           // configure cell
           return cell
       }
       .disposed(by: disposeBag)
   ```

Both have pros and cons. The second one has a reference to the `tableView` which sometimes can be very handy.

Comment: Thanks @au-ris, Second one is great, and  it works for me.

Comment: I got the same problem. Your methods don't seem to fix it for me. This is how I bind: `Orders.getList(shopId, status: .active).bind(to: rxTableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))` where `Orders.getList()` is of type `Observable<>` and `dataSource` is of type `RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<MyTableSection>`. `MyTableSection` conforms to `Equatable`. Any suggestions?